# Supervised Classification gives "Directory(error)" ans "SR_B1" missing error in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, image-classification, landsat-5

I am trying to run supervised classification on single date, cloud free, Landsat 5 collection 2 level 2 image. I have imported the point shapefiles of different classes with class values and have merged those training data. After running the code, I am getting an error displaying "Property "SR_B1" misiing". I tried resolving it but could not succeed. I am copying the code link along with the code also. How can I fix this?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/8566667dc91457b4811665c227e804b2

```js
var dws= table.geometry();
Map.addLayer(dws,{},'Dalma Wildlife Sanctuary');
Map.centerObject(dws,11);

var band= ['SR_B1', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4'];

var vis= {min:0.0,max:0.3,bands:['SR_B4','SR_B3','SR_B2']};

//scalling of image 
var scalled = function(image){
  return(image.multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2).copyProperties(image,['system:time_start']));
};
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//filter image based on date and cloudcover as well as bands
                 
var l1995 = L5.filterDate('1995-12-11', '1995-12-13')//change the year 
               .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than',10)
               .map(scalled)
               .filterBounds(dws)
               .select(band);
                    
//display image
Map.addLayer(l1995, vis, "FCC");
print('Single Image for December 1995',l1995);

//Display No. of images
print('Total image in the collection',l1995.size());

//Converting Image collection into a single image and display the image
var L1995 = l1995.first().clip(dws);
Map.addLayer(L1995, vis, "False Color 1995 of DWS");


//Merging training data
var training= training1.merge(training2).merge(training3).merge(training4);
print('Merged training data',training);

// Display the training data.
Map.addLayer(training,{}, "GCP");


// Overlay the point on the image to get training data.
var trainImage = L1995.select(band).sampleRegions({
  collection: training,
  properties:['Landcover'],
  scale: 30
});
print(trainImage);
 
// Train a classifier.
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileCart().train({
  features: training, 
  classProperty: 'Landcover', 
  inputProperties: band
});
print(classifier.explain());

// Classify the image.
var classified = L1995.select(band).classify(classifier);
Map.addLayer(classified.clip(dws), {min: 0, max: 3, palette: ['gray', 'brown', 'blue', 'green']}, 'cart');
```

Comment: Your uploaded tables do not have any properties (i.e. attributes). Your code expects a column named 'Landcover' containing class values. Add them to the shapefiels and upload the table again.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried the corrections suggested by you and it worked. 
@spatialthoughts